# Add Dynamic Wrapper div to a Row

Tags: theming

I have buttons below a slideshow I have created. I want them to be centered whether there be 1, 2, etc. I'm looking to have a wrapper div surrounding them with a class name of "button-count-x" (x being number of buttons). I've tried using a 'foreach' loop and counting the number of $row's, but that is not working.

Note: I am using the "Views Slideshow" module and am using the view's respective 'views-view.tpl.php' file.

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>

<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
<?php if (!empty($field->separator)): ?>
<?php $count ++; ?>
<?php print $field->separator; ?>
```

```
<div class = "test"><?php print $count; ?></div>

<?php print $field->wrapper_prefix; ?>
<?php print $field->label_html; ?>
<?php print $field->content; ?>
<?php print $field->wrapper_suffix; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Post a code that fails for you. We can help, but we can't write things for you from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

that's not much to go on, so I'll assume that the module generates one button per slide in the slideshow, and you want them centered underneath the image area ?

It's hard to know without the markup, but a couple of css selectors should do the trick.

for the containing div, if it has an id, or a uniquely addressable class, try something like this:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and if the button divs or whatever have no convenient id or class, address them something like this:

```
#container > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I think you may be better off sticking to css. Post the relevant rendered html, and perhaps we can help.